# Secure file upload for PDF only

Tags: php, sql, file, security, pdf

I am trying to create a secure file upload using PHP 7+ where I **only allow PDF files**. I found a lot of posts on this topic on different websites but couldn't find a complete solution that ensures that no harmful files can be uploaded this way.

So far I have the following code. Can someone tell me if I am missing any important steps here or if anything should be changed or removed in my code?

(**Note:** I am not interested in the old x-pdf file types.)

```
<?php
    include 'session.php';
    include 'header.php';

    if (empty($_FILES['files'])) {
        echo json_encode(['error'=>'No files found for upload.']); 
        return;
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['csrfToken'])) {
        if(hash_equals($_SESSION['csrfToken'], $_POST['csrfToken'])) {
            $postData = $_POST;
            $files = $_FILES['files'];
            $uploadRef = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', '', $_GET['uploadRef']);
            $categoryId = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', '', $_GET['categoryId']);
            $tags = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9,]/', '', $_GET['tagsList']);
            $success = null;

            $paths= [];
            $filenames = $files['name'];

            for($i=0; $i < count($filenames); $i++){
                if($_FILES['file']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                    die('Upload failed with error ' . $_FILES['file']['error']);
                }
                
                $fileTitle = $files['name'][$i];
                $fileTitle = substr($fileTitle, 0 , (strrpos($fileTitle, ".")));
                $fileExtensions = explode('.', basename($filenames[$i]));
                $fileExtension = strtolower(array_pop($fileExtensions));
                $ok = false;
                switch($fileExtension) {
                   case 'pdf':
                        $ok = true;
                   default:
                       die('Unknown/not permitted file type');
                }
                
                $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
                $mime = finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
                $ok = false;
                switch($mime) {
                   case 'application/pdf':
                        $ok = true;
                   default:
                       die('Unknown/not permitted file type');
                }
                
                $uploadId = md5(uniqid()) . '_' . $i;
                $target = 'uploads' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $uploadId . '.' . $fileExtension;
                if(move_uploaded_file($files['tmp_name'][$i], $target)) {
                    $success = true;
                    $paths[] = $target;
                    
                    $conn = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPw, $dbName);
                    if($conn->connect_error) {
                        exit($trans['errorConnectionFailedTxt'][$lang]);
                    }
                    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
                    $conn->set_charset('utf8mb4');
                        
                    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO uploads (uploadId, uploadRef, categoryId, tags, fileTitle, fileExtension) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
                    $stmt->bind_param("ssssss", $uploadId, $uploadRef, $categoryId, $tags, $fileTitle, $fileExtension);  
                    $stmt->execute();
                    
                    $stmt->close();
                    $conn->close();     
                } else {
                    $success = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if ($success === true) {
                $output = [];
            } elseif ($success === false) {
                $output = ['error'=>'Error while uploading images. Contact the system administrator'];
                foreach ($paths as $file) {
                    unlink($file);
                }
            } else {
                $output = ['error'=>'No files were processed.'];
            }

            unset($postData);
            
            echo json_encode($output);
        } else {
             echo json_encode('invalid CSRF token');
        }
    } else {
         echo json_encode('no CSRF token');
    }
?>
```

Comment: How many `header('Location...')` calls are you planning to make?

Comment: @mickmackusa: One. Why ?

Comment: It's inside a loop.  Do you mean to redirect?

Comment: @mickmackusa: Thanks. Yes, I mean to redirect after successful upload, but only once (also in case of multiple files) so I may have placed this wrongly.

Comment: You may edit your script until you receive an answer.

Comment: My main concern is that someone can take a harmful file and just make it look like a pdf so I want to prevent that this could be misused to upload a shell, exe or other harmful file.

Comment: That may be true, but we will review your entire script.  There are several things to improve in your script.

Comment: Ok. I removed the header completely as it is not a must-have here.

Comment: @mickmackusa: Are you still looking into this ?

Comment: At 7am on a Sunday I am sleeping in my bed.

Comment: Sorry, I am in another time zone.

Answer (score 2):

### Guard statements

```
if(!empty($_POST['csrfToken'])) {
    if(hash_equals($_SESSION['csrfToken'], $_POST['csrfToken'])) {
```

I think that this should be performed in a separate method that validates tokens. Furthermore, I think that this should end in an HTTP error (as indicated by the other answer).

Above is called a "guard statement", it checks if the state or parameter is valid before the method is executed. If it isn't valid, it should terminate it. Termination can be performed locally, you definitely don't want to have to scroll through the method to find:

```
    } else {
         echo json_encode('invalid CSRF token');
    }
} else {
     echo json_encode('no CSRF token');
}
```

at the end. Furthermore, if you simply exit the method you remove a layer of indentation making the method less complex to read.

### Unclear regular expressions

```
$uploadRef = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', '', $_GET['uploadRef']);
```

This should also be a method, not so much because the regular expression is hard to understand (the "what"), but it isn't clear **why** it is performed.

### Success?

```
 $success = null;
```

Success is a boolean, it should not be used as a variable with three values. Use either two variables or an enumeration. Furthermore, `$success` is a terrible bad name, try `filesUploaded` or similar.

If we'd check that `count($filenames)` is zero beforehand we can simply set the output beforehand and skip the rest of the execution (remember the guard statements). Programming is all about limiting complexity.

### Recovering C programmer

```
 $ok = false;
```

Not required if you `die` anyway, right?

### Not so unique

```
 uniqid()
```

"This function does not guarantee uniqueness of return value."<sup>[1](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php#refsect1-function.uniqid-description)</sup> Um, right. This is just waiting to fail horribly, whatever you do with it. Using `md5()` on it will not accomplish *anything*. Extension with a counter will help unless the same folder is used by parallel processes (is that possible?).

### The sequel

The SQL statements should be in a separate method, e.g. `createFileUploadReport`. If you make a separate class you can even use different ways of reporting, e.g. reporting to console or log file instead, so you can test your method without SQL server present.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure how secure the MIME type testing is. I would not be surprised if it can be fooled to some extend.

Answer (score 1):

### Bug / Logic error

The two `switch` statements have one case plus the default case. In both switch statements the `default` case is always executed. Perhaps a better understanding of how `switch` statements work would be useful. Also, for a single case it doesn't make sense to use a `switch` statement - a simple `if` statement would suffice.

### Inconsistent return types

In some cases an array is passed to `json_encode()` and used with an `echo` statement, yet in other cases `die()` is called. The json encoded arrays would have me believe this script is used in conjunction with an asynchronous loading mechanism (e.g. AJAX), but that would likely be thrown off if `die()` or `exit()` is used, unless it looks for both arrays and simple strings.

Then apparently when the upload is successful there is this code:

> ```
> if ($success === true) {
>      $output = [];
> ```

That doesn't seem to be very helpful for the front-end code.

It would also be wise to use [HTTP response codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) - e.g. 200 to indicate success, 422 for invalid input, etc.

### returning early

When the first condition, i.e. `if (empty($_FILES['files'])) {` evaluates to `true` then the JSON response is returned with the appropriate error message. The other conditions that lead to error messages should follow the same fashion e.g. empty value in `$_POST['csrfToken']`, etc.  Doing so will decrease the amount of indentation for the rest of the code. For more information on this topic see [this presentation about cleaning up code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GtB5DAfOWMQ) where Rafael Dohms talks about many ways to keep code lean - like avoiding the `else` keyword ([see the slides here](https://www.slideshare.net/rdohms/bettercode-phpbenelux212alternate/11-OC_1Only_one_indentation_level)).

Because it doesn’t depend on the loop iterator variable, this block can be moved above the `for` loop:

> ```
> if($_FILES['file']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
>     die('Upload failed with error ' . $_FILES['file']['error']);
> }
> ```

### checking MIME type

Instead of calling `finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE)` just to get the mime-type, the [`mime-content-type()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) function could be used.

```
$mime = mime-content-type($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])
```

Additionally, the mime-type may be provided from the browser in `$_FILES['files']['type'][$i]` though it "*not checked on the PHP side and therefore don't take its value for granted.*"<sup>[1](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php#example-395)</sup>

### variable `$postData` - really needed?

After `postData` is assigned, it only appears to be used in one spot- passed to `unset()`. It hardly seems necessary...

### variadic field name checks

While the form submitted to this script is not included one can only guess as to the fields. The script checks both `$_FILES['files']` as well as `$_FILES['file']` - while the former most likely allows multiple files to be uploaded, are there really two different file input fields?

### database query in loop

The code currently inserts records into the database on each iteration of the loop. Consider using only one statement to insert all records. This will minimize database connections (which can increase execution time) as well as prevent invalid data from being inserted (e.g. if first file was valid but subsequent files were not).

### regular expressions to replace characters

The regular expressions could perhaps be simplified using the [character type](https://www.php.net/manual/en/parle.regex.charclass.php) `\w` though that includes the underscore characters i.e. `_` but must those be removed? Also not that `preg_replace()` won't safely clean multi-byte strings so consider that if unicode strings need to be supported.